# Compare first array value with string inside if

Tags: php, arrays

The `if` statements in the following code are not working and I don't know why. When I use `var_dump` or `print_r` it shows the value correctly but the statements are not evaluating `True`.

```
<?php
$array_log = explode("\n", file_get_contents('log.txt'));
$ante_ultimo_elemento =  count($array_log)-2;
$valor_ante_ultimo = $array_log[$ante_ultimo_elemento];


$valor_limpio  = utf8_decode($valor_ante_ultimo);
$porciones1 = explode("=", $valor_limpio);

$valor_limpio2  = $porciones1[1];
$porciones2 = explode('?', $valor_limpio2);
$estado = $porciones2[0];

if($porciones2[0] === "Backup completato con successo"){
    $estado_final = "COMPLETO";
}

if($porciones2[0] == "Nessun backup effettuato"){
    $estado_final = 'CERO';
}

if($porciones2[0] == "Errore nella procedura di backup"){
    $estado_final = 'ERROR';
}
?>
```

**log.txt:**

```
[Log Info]
BkpSet00.bks\Html-Log00.zip=Backup completato con successo÷00 : 00 : 59÷231466496
BkpSet00.bks\Html-Log01.zip=Errore nella procedura di backup÷00 : 00 : 02÷0
BkpSet00.bks\Html-Log02.zip=Backup completato con successo÷00 : 00 : 43÷216655360
BkpSet01.bks\Html-Log00.zip=Nessun backup effettuato÷00 : 00 : 02÷0
BkpSet01.bks\Html-Log01.zip=Errore nella procedura di backup÷00 : 00 : 46÷0
BkpSet02.bks\Html-Log00.zip=Nessun backup effettuato÷00 : 00 : 02÷0
BkpSet02.bks\Html-Log01.zip=Backup completato con successo÷00 : 00 : 14÷216655360
BkpSet03.bks\Html-Log00.zip=Nessun backup effettuato÷00 : 00 : 02÷0
BkpSet03.bks\Html-Log01.zip=Backup completato con successo÷00 : 00 : 17÷231663104
BkpSet04.bks\Html-Log00.zip=Backup completato con successo÷00 : 00 : 16÷231663104
BkpSet00.bks\Html-Log03.zip=Backup completato con successo÷00 : 00 : 13÷216655360
BkpSet00.bks\Html-Log04.zip=Backup completato con successo÷00 : 00 : 09÷216655360
BkpSet16.bks\Html-Log00.zip=Backup completato con successo÷00 : 01 : 33÷1462158767
BkpSet05.bks\Html-Log00.zip=Errore nella procedura di backup÷11 : 18 : 30÷235564152142
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you please share a sample log entry?

Comment: Sure, there I added, thank you @Cunning!

Comment: about `utf8_decode` is there a reason for that? because in the php manual it notes `This function converts the string data from the UTF-8 encoding to ISO-8859-1. Bytes in the string which are not valid UTF-8, and UTF-8 characters which do not exist in ISO-8859-1 (that is, characters above U+00FF) are replaced with ?.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://3v4l.org/rH8In) piece of code does the trick. Note that since 3v4l site can't read from a file, I have to make a substitution. just omit that part

```
// read from file. this function puts file content in an array line by line
$array_log = file('log.txt');
// finding the desired element. count()-2 means the one before the final entry. count()-1 means the final entry.
$ante_ultimo_elemento =  count($array_log)-2;
// taking the entry apart into its pieces using regex.
preg_match('/(?P<file>.*?)=(?P<message>[\w\s]*?)÷(?P<time>\d{2}\s?:\s?\d{2}\s?:\s?\d{2}\s?)÷(?<last_part>\d*)/', $array_log[$ante_ultimo_elemento], $estado);
// to avoid notice on the occasion that no statement could be matched, I highly recommend using if-elseif-else statement to avoid unwanted situations;
// or better still, use switch-case-default
switch($estado['message'])
{
    case "Backup completato con successo": {
        $estado_final = "COMPLETO";
        break;
    }
    case "Nessun backup effettuato": {
        $estado_final = 'CERO';
        break;
    }
    case "Errore nella procedura di backup": {
        $estado_final = 'ERROR';
        break;
    }
    default: {
        $estado_final = 'FATAL ERROR';
        break;
    }
}
echo $estado_final;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! The code from Cunning is working perfectly, I added an upvote but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Use strpos since the test is including data other than the string you seek:

```
  $array_log = explode("\n", file_get_contents('log.txt'));
  $ante_ultimo_elemento =  count($array_log)-2;
  $valor_ante_ultimo = $array_log[$ante_ultimo_elemento];


  $valor_limpio  = utf8_decode($valor_ante_ultimo);
  $porciones1 = explode("=", $valor_limpio);
  /*
      [0] => BkpSet05.bks\Html-Log00.zip
      [1] => Errore nella procedura di backup�11 : 18 : 30�23556415214
  */

  $valor_limpio2  = $porciones1[1];
  $porciones2 = explode('?', $valor_limpio2);
  /*
      [0] => Errore nella procedura di backup�11 : 18 : 30�23556415214
  */
  $estado = $porciones2[0];

  if (strpos($porciones2[0], "Backup completato con successo") !== false){
      $estado_final = "COMPLETO";
  }

  if (strpos($porciones2[0], "Nessun backup effettuato") !== false){
      $estado_final = 'CERO';
  }

  if (strpos($porciones2[0], "Errore nella procedura di backup") !== false){
      $estado_final = 'ERROR';
  }

  echo 'estado_final '.$estado_final.'<br>';
```

Comment: I think your `strpos` is backward.

Comment: @don'tpanic why why why is my strpos always backwards - array needle haystack str haystack needle, array needle haystack str haystack needle, array needle haystack str haystack needle - okay, maybe i'll remember - thx!

Comment: No worries. I've been doing this for quite a while now and I still have to go back to the manual to remember order of arguments. It might be easier if PHP was more consistent, but then again, I usually can't remember what I had for breakfast.